# jQuery for consecutive events in a dropdown menu without page refresh

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, drop-down-menu, ujs

I have a dropdown function that is filled with various notifications.
Some of these notifications can be dismissed, at which point the number of notifications is decremented by 1.

But, once a notification is dismissed, the page refreshes and I have to open up the dropdown menu again to (potentially) dismiss the next notification...
This is very inefficient if I wanted to dismiss n+ notifications, consecutively.

So, ***what I'd like to do is to (once the dropdown menu is once)* 1. dismiss consecutive notifications**, but **2. dismiss notifications *with* the dropdown open** and **3. without a page refresh.**

The jquery code to decrement the number of notifications is

```
$('header .ajax-dropdown input.unread').on 'change', -> 
  count = $('header .ajax-dropdown [data-action-needed-count]').data('action-needed-count')
  $('header .activity-dropdown .notification-badge').html count
```

I'm a jQuery newb and I had the code handed down to me...
Now I need to make sense of it all...

Thanks for any suggestions/advice!

Comment: I'd love to help, but I can't duplicate what you're talking about from the code you've provided. Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You're right!  
Let me ruminate on this a while longer and I'll definitely put some more context!